How can Android devices light up after receiving notifications when the screen is locked
I set this configuration in my Java project:
setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder().setPriority(Priority.HIGH).build())

but it can only light up once, and subsequent messages won't light up. What's going on?
I hope that Android devices will be able to light up every time they receive a notification after the screen is locked.

I think it will only light up for first time for a notification unless it is a notification with different id or from different app. What you can try is: change the notification id every time and don't forget to remove the old notification.
